# Plone date translations broken

Tags: internationalization, plone, plone-4.x

Somehow after running buildout and restarting my website, dates translations are not correct. I receive `28 month_aug_abbr 2015`, not `28 Aug 2015`.

Comment: Any changes on the buildout?

Comment: Yes, a lot. It's a complex project. Maybe it is related to plone.app.locales version. Not sure...

Comment: Throwing in a wild guess: I encountered small issues with the newest P4-versions, also concerning translations, but don't have time to track them down, so I stay with Plone-4.3.4 for now. Is your Plone-version higher and if so, does the error also occur with P-4.3.4?

Comment: I think you are right. Plone 4.3.3 -> 4.3.6 was one on my changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When this happens I usually check zope.conf.
It should include this environment variables:

```
PTS_LANGUAGES it en
LANG it_IT.utf8
TZ Europe/Rome
zope_i18n_compile_mo_files true
```

You can configure them with buildout doing something like this:

```
[instance-settings]
environment-vars +=
    PTS_LANGUAGES it en
    LANG it_IT.utf8
    TZ Europe/Rome
    zope_i18n_compile_mo_files true
```

If you use complex buildouts you should pay attention to the presence of lines with "environment-vars =" (note the missing + before the equal): they may override your modification.

Use ./bin/buildout annotate to debug your buildout.

Comment: Solved with: bin/pocompile (Added zest.pocompile in my .cfg). Maybe it is the same...